# I have having trouble adding color to my heat map as it says scale for fill is already present

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

```
HP4 <- ggplot(Sabinecompressedkpa, aes(Distance, Depth)) +                           
  geom_tile(aes(fill = kpa))+scale_fill_gradient("YlOrRd")+
  scale_fill_continuous(limits=c(0,50))
HP4
```

Error message
Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will
replace the existing scale.

I tried to do a manual fill but they keep giving me this error
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple things you would like to notice:

1. `scale_fill_gradient("YlOrRd")+ scale_fill_continuous(limits=c(0,50))` you have two scale_fill_* that is the reason why you get the warning message
2. `scale_fill_gradient("YlOrRd")` should not work, as `scale_fill_gradient` needs you to supply the `high` and `low` values.

The solution is to combine the two scale_fill_* and you should use `scale_fill_distiller` instead.

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot() +
... +
scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlOrRd", limits = c(0, 50))
```